# Best way to navigate between layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm pretty new to Android, and I was wondering how others usually trigger layout navigation. To clarify, I have text ("Pick people") that, when clicked, causes a new pane to animate in with a picker interface. Hitting another button animates the first pane back in.

I'm just using a ViewSwitcher as the parent of two views, let's call them A and B. A contains a TextView for the text, since I didn't want all the chrome of a Button, and adding an onclick handler to call showNext() on the parent. At that point, pane B slides in.

However, I noticed some "unclean" aspects of this:

- I want different animations for the two views. When sliding in view B, the new view should enter from the right and the old view should slide out to the left. When sliding in view A, the directions should be reversed since it's going "back". As of now I'm swapping the animations right before changing views.
- Tapping the text twice causes the animations to occur twice. As of now I need to set more state variables to figure out whether to honor the click or not.

Are there built-in widgets that I should be using better suited for this?

Comment: Why not just start a second `Activity`? Maybe use `startActivityForResult`. But then to go back to Activity A call `finish()` in Activity B.